# Overload conflict in ML (SML/NJ)

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have written the following piece of code for ML:

```
fun get_digits (0, s) = s
        | get_digits (d, s) = get_digits( d div 10, (d mod 10) :: s)
        | get_digits n = get_digits( n div 10, [n mod 10] );
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Operator and operand do not agree (overload conflict)
operator domain: [mod ty] * [mod ty]
operand: ([mod ty] * [mod ty] list) * [int ty]
in expression
n div 10
Error: Operator and operand do not agree (overload conflict)
operator domain: [mod ty] * [mod ty]
operand: ([mod ty] * [mod ty] list) * [int ty]
in expression
n mod 10
```

Can someone explain what this means and what changes i should make? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your first two cases say that the argument of `get_digits` is a pair of an integer and a list.

Then your third case tries to apply `div` and `mod` to such a pair, which doesn't work.

Since you can't define a function that takes either a number or a pair as its argument, you need to use two functions:

```
fun get_digits' (0, s) = s
  | get_digits' (d, s) = get_digits' (d div 10, (d mod 10)::s);

fun get_digits n = get_digits' (n div 10, [n mod 10]);
```

You can define the helper function locally in `get_digits`, of course.